# Show that $(X,d)$ is a separable metric space.

Tags: metric-spaces, separable-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space such that every uncountable subset of $X$ has a limit point. Then show that $(X,d)$ is a separable metric space.

How do I construct a countable dense subset of $X$ from the given hypothesis? Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using Zorn's Lemma you can construct maximal sets $S_{\epsilon}$ such that any two points of $S_{\epsilon}$ are separated by distance $\epsilon$. If all these are countable then we get separability. Otherwise the hypothesis is contradicted.

Comment: We call a subset A of X ε-separated if for any x,y in A, it holds that $ d(x,y) \geq ε$. A metric space is separable if and only if every ε-separated set is (at most) countable.

Comment: Is union of $\varepsilon$-separated sets $\varepsilon$-separated @KaviRamaMurthy sir?

Comment: Union of any family of $\epsilon$ separated sets forming a chain under inclusion is $\epsilon$ separated. Apply Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: If you take $x \neq y$ in this union then $x$ and $y$ are both in some member of the chain. So they are saparated by distance $\epsilon$.

Comment: So the only thing which remains to prove is that if all such maximal $\varepsilon$-separated sets $S_{\varepsilon}$ are countable then $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} S_{\frac {1} {n}}$ is dense in $X.$ Am I right @KaviRamaMurthy sir?

Comment: Exactly. That finishes the proof.

Comment: Thank you very much @KaviRamaMurthy sir for your kind help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116009/discussion-between-anacardium-and-kavi-rama-murthy).